# MATLAB parfor - cannot determine whether "ModelUtil" refers to a function or variable?

Tags: matlab

I am calling external functions in my `parfor` loop as follows.

```
parfor idx = 1:2
    import com.comsol.model.*
    import com.comsol.model.util.*

    model = ModelUtil.create('Model');
    model.modelNode.create('comp1');

    model.geom.create('geom1', 2);
    model.geom('geom1').feature.create('sq1', 'Square');
    model.geom('geom1').feature('sq1').set('size', '0.03125');
    model.geom('geom1').feature('sq1').setIndex('pos', '0', 0);
    model.geom('geom1').feature('sq1').setIndex('pos', '0', 1);
    model.geom('geom1').run;
end

Error: MATLAB cannot determine whether "ModelUtil" refers to a function or variable.
See Parallel for Loops in MATLAB, "Unambiguous Variable Names".
```

After reading [the "Unambiguous Variable Names" part in the MATLAB `parfor` documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/pdf_doc/distcomp/distcomp.pdf), I pretty much understand why this error occurs. However, I have no idea how to fix it.

Comment: Have you tried using the fully qualified name for `ModelUtil` instead of importing? I.e.: `model = com.comsol.model.util.ModelUtil.create('Model');`

Comment: @Alan I just checked, but it did not work. `com` becomes unknown this time. `Error: MATLAB cannot determine whether "com" refers to a function or variable.
See Parallel for Loops in MATLAB, "Unambiguous Variable Names".` Any other solution? It work while in normal for loop.

Comment: Right, this sounds like a class path error. I believe comsol is a third party library, so you need to include the jar file in the classpath for each machine running the when you are creating the spmd job. The easiest way would be to add it to the filepath of the cluster or job as appropriate.

Comment: @Alan Yes, it is a 3rd-party library. But this thing works perfectly in for loop. I never take special care of it in the normal for loop. Why in parfor do I have to " include the jar file in the class path", please?

Comment: Right, In a for loop you are working with a single instance of matlab on a single machine with a single classpath. With a parfor loop you are potentially* working on several machines, with several instances of matlab, each with their own classpath. It may be the case that these machines won't all have access to the location where your third party library's jar file is, so you have to explicitly provide it to all of them. (* Matlab doesn't know if you are or are not, so it has to assume you are using multiple machines)

Answer (score 2):

I encountered the same problem with .Net objects.  Like you, I found it works perfectly in non-parallel mode and the problem only occurs with parfor.

This is not a question of paths, this is purely a Matlab syntax/parser problem.

As a workaround, I wrapped the operations in a separate Matlab function so that within the scope of the parfor it is no longer ambiguous.  Within the (otherwise unnecessary) function it has no trouble resolving the class, even when called from within parfor.

Answer (score 0):

Vector's solution didn't work for me. The thing is that the different workers don't see the library you are using: you have to update the javapath in the `parfor` with `javaaddpath`.