# MATLAB parfor error: function or variable?

Tags: matlab, parallel-processing

The following code:

```
matlabpool('open','local',2)

parfor i=1:5
    proc = System.Diagnostics.Process;
end
```

results in an error:

```
Error: MATLAB cannot determine whether "System" refers to a function or variable.
```

However, when I execute the parfor loop again (after the error), it runs through! I found a couple of similar questions, but I wasn't able to implement the suggested solutions.

[MATLAB parfor - cannot determine whether "ModelUtil" refers to a function or variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24558249/matlab-parfor-cannot-determine-whether-modelutil-refers-to-a-function-or-var)

[MATLAB using parfor (parallel computing toolbox) and custom packages with +](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25898244/matlab-using-parfor-parallel-computing-toolbox-and-custom-packages-with)

I can't wrap my mind around why the loop runs the second time. If I then call

```
matlabpool close
```

and execute the whole script again, the error appears once again. So it only happens the first time after the pool was initiated. Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because any variable or function you use in a `parfor` loop must be defined *explicitly* in the code **at parsing time**. If there is any ambiguity, Matlab opt to throw an error rather than messing up by assuming.

Just define an anonymous function that create the object you want before the `parfor` loop, then you can use it as will *within* the `parfor` loop.

This run fine on my machine (*Matlab R2013a*):

```
getSystemProcess = @() System.Diagnostics.Process ;
parfor i=1:5
    proc = getSystemProcess();
end
```

---

Read this Matlab chapter for more informations on how the variable/function names are interpreted in a `parfor` loop: [Unambiguous Variable Names](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/distcomp/variables-and-transparency-in-parfor-loops.html#brdtqhq-1)

Comment: With your suggestion I don't get the error anymore, but instead two warnings appear: `Warning: Objects of class 'parallel.cluster.Local' cannot be saved to MAT files.` and `Warning: Objects of class 'parallel.cluster.Local' cannot be loaded correctly from MAT files.` The behaviour is rather chaotic though, sometimes it runs without any warning too. I found that there is a difference if I execute the parfor loop in a function as opposed to a script (or selecting the lines and pushing F9). Any ideas please? I am also using R2013a.

Comment: that seems like a completely different issue. You are trying to save some object (`parallel.cluster.Local`) in a `.mat` file and Matlab warn you that it may not work properly. I suggest you post a new question with details of your code. Don't forget to detail what is the difference you observe when running in function and in script mode.

Comment: Having started with a clear workspace today, I am not able to reproduce the warnings anymore. I wasn't saving anything, just running the minimal example above. Let me hope it was only some anomaly. Shuold it reappear again, I will post a new question. Thank you!